# Syntax issue in batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, registry

I have been working on this script for a little and I am new to writing batch files. I know my syntaxs is wrong and need some help.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "ports=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports"
for /f %%I in ( 'reg query "%ports%"')
do (
    echo %%I | findstr /i "c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1  reg delete "%ports%" /v "%%I" /f    
)
```

Comment: I still receive a error from that code.

Comment: try with `for /f "delims=" %%I in ( 'reg query "%ports%"')`

Comment: That doesn't work for me @npocmaka

Comment: and `do` must be on the same line as `for /f` . And remove `"delims="`

Comment: Thanks alot that does work now. Why does it have to be on the same line? @npocmaka

Comment: Originally, batch was executed physical-line by physical-line. There were no line-continuation facilities, and you could only execute one statement per line. `&` and parenthesised multi-line statement blocks were then added, but the original parsing was merely expanded. IOW, it's a hang-over. There's a similar quirk with `IF...ELSE` where the `ELSE (` must be on the same line as the `)` closing the `IF` when-true.

Comment: it is possible to use new line , but should also use a caret: `for /f  %%I in ( 'reg query "%ports%"')^<NEW-LINE>do somenething`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ports=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports"
for /f %%I in ( 
    'reg query "%ports%"' 
        ) do (
    echo %%I | findstr /i "c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1  reg delete "%ports%" /v "%%I" /f    
)
```

Comment: This works except that it's deleting everything and not just the string it finds @captcha. I have a bunch of lines that are c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps which I am trying to remove but it also is removing stuff like FILE: , LPT1, ect.

Comment: Sorry Figured it out. I needed IF NOT.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments also point out, cmd wants "do" on the same line as the closing parenthesis of the previous expression. You're not using delayed expansion. It's not an error, but I see no reason to turn it on.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ports=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports"
for /f %%I in ( 'reg query "%ports%"' ) do (
    echo %%I | findstr /i "c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1  reg delete "%ports%" /v "%%I" /f    
)
```

Curiously, this experiment worked:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (
'dir /b'
) DO (
@ECHO %%i
)
```